# Span not showing in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="calender">
<span class="moduleItemDateCreated-month">Jan</span>
<span class="moduleItemDateCreated-day">24</span>
</div>
```

Styled with this CSS:

```
#calender {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.moduleItemDateCreated-month {
    background-color: #999999;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 56px;
}

.moduleItemDateCreated-day {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    width:56px;
}
```

In IE7 the second span is not visible, does anyone know why?

[Here is a temporary link](http://boardsales.test.digiflipconcepts.com/new/)

[image: here's a screenshot]

Comment: ok thanks for the comments, so I've set the height of the container and changed the span to inline-block but still no joy...

Answer (score 1):

You can define in your CSS the following

```
 .moduleItemDateCreated-month, .moduleItemDateCreated-day{
      display:inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that fix but unfortunately it is still not working, although now when you hover over the li in which it is all contained the background shows, very odd!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into a Float bug in IE. Since you know what the height and width of the wrapper div will be, you could specify this in the CSS.

If you are looking for more solutions, there is plenty of help in the IE float but front: https://www.google.com/search?q=ie7+float+right+bug

Comment: thanks I've heard of that bug but have never run into it before, I'll look into it. I added the height but still no joy